# How to enable CORS handler in light-4j service

Tags: cors, light-4j

Question regarding CORS:

I used light-codegen with a swagger api. Now I want to enable CORS on my microservice.

To accomplish this, I did the following:

1. added a cors.yml in the config folder (same location as swagger.json, service.yml, server.yml ...)
2. added dependency to pom.xml: groupId: com.networknt artifactId: cors
3. added the following line to service.yml, right under swaggerHandler: - com.networknt.cors.CorsHttpHandler

but the server does not add any cors header to the response. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are following an older version of the tutorial and trying to upgrade to the latest version of light-4j framework. The configuration files have been changed a lot and that might contribute the complexity.

I have upgraded and published CORS tutorial and there a link to the working version on github. Let me know if you encounter any issue. Thanks.

https://doc.networknt.com/tutorial/cors/

Comment: i too faced the same issue and followed the tutorial but it didn't add the options handler...The github project reference in the cors tutorial is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer, we need to add [PathHandlerProvider file](https://github.com/networknt/light-example-4j/blob/master/rest/openapi/cors/src/main/java/com/networknt/cors/PathHandlerProvider.java) in com.networknt.cors package. Need to remove the handlers.yml file from config folder. Just double check whether the service.yml file is same as in the [git hub repo project](https://github.com/networknt/light-example-4j/blob/master/rest/openapi/cors/src/main/resources/config/).

This actually handles pre-flight request(OPTIONS) for cross origin requests with possible methods for CORS.

```
curl -k -H "Origin: http://test123.com" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST"  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With"  -X OPTIONS --verbose https://localhost:8443/v1/postData
```

Response was coming with following headers:

```
< access-control-allow-headers: X-Requested-With
< server: L
< access-control-allow-credentials: true
< content-length: 0
< access-control-allow-methods: GET
< access-control-allow-methods: POST
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for bringing this issue up. The cors handler works for both service.yml and handlers.yml configuration. The tutorial is old and used service.yml for configuration. I will add another tutorial to set it up in the handlers.yml file. Also, I want to point it out that we don't use CORS in most of the cases as we are using the light-router to serve the single page application and all services are aggregated on the same router instance. https://doc.networknt.com/tutorial/router/

Comment: when i was using handlers.yml, it was saying method not implemented, probably we need to do different configuration, i guess. Will check on the light router and get back.